Is there a sound way to convert/transmute from Arc<String> to Arc<Vec<u8>>
String and Vec<u8> have the same memory layout, although this is not guaranteed.
String also has an into_bytes method returning a Vec<u8>.
Is there a sound way to convert from an Arc<String> to an Arc<Vec<u8>> without allocating any memory for a new Arc? We can assert that the arc refcount is 1. I don't mind using unsafe. I also don't mind asserting that they have the same size / falling back to alloc in that case. Is this possible?

Aside: do you absolutely need the double-indirection (eg because you need the underlying buffer to be growable)?  If not, you could/should use Arc<str> and Arc<[u8]>.

They either have the same memory layout or they don't.  String does not have any #[repr] specified, so it has the default (Rust) representation which is completely unspecified apart from soundness guarantees; you'd need it to have #[repr(transparent)] for a transmute to be sound.

Also, is it such a huge cost to deallocate the Arc (which is really quite small, holding only the refcounts and three-pointer-width String), perform the conversion and then allocate a new Arc?

@eggyal: Sorry for not answering sooner: Yes, I need the modification capabilities, and this part of the code was benchmarked to be worth the optimization effort. But I get that it's a bit of an uncommon pattern, so fair question. Thank you for the great answer btw.

@eggyal's approach is unfortunately fundamentally unsound with Stacked Borrows. Here is a somewhat different approach that is sound (I hope):
use std::mem::{align_of, size_of};
use std::sync::Arc;

// We can check that size and alignment match at compile-time, which saves us from
// performing these checks at runtime.
const _: () = {
    assert!(size_of::<String>() == size_of::<Vec<u8>>());
    assert!(align_of::<String>() == align_of::<Vec<u8>>());
};

pub fn convert(mut arc: Arc<String>) -> Arc<Vec<u8>> {
    Arc::get_mut(&mut arc).unwrap();

    let raw_string = Arc::into_raw(arc).cast_mut();
    let raw_bytes = raw_string.cast::<Vec<u8>>();

    // SAFETY: We don't drop the returned string, panic will just drop the string
    // but leak the `Arc` (which is why there won't be a double drop),
    // and we just transform the string and write it back.
    let string = unsafe { raw_string.read() };

    let bytes = string.into_bytes();

    // SAFETY:
    //  - We are the only one pointing to this `Arc`, so no data race can occur.
    //  - `String` and `Vec<u8>` have the same size and alignment, so the write is in bounds.
    //  - We converted the `String` to `Vec` using its methods, so we know it is valid.
    unsafe { raw_bytes.write(bytes) };

    // SAFETY: We transformed the `String` into `Vec<u8>`, so it is now initialized as `Vec<u8>`.
    // And we didn't involve reference at all, so we have no aliasing problems.
    unsafe { Arc::from_raw(raw_bytes) }
}


This looks like an nice improvement. But I don't quite understand why we need the abort on panic. Isn't the worst case just that we leak the Arc and / or the String? Why can't we unwind? Double free shouldn't happen here afaict?

@ChrisB You are right. For some reason I thought that we would drop both the string and the Arc, creating a double free.
